# Meteor S3 file upload with Slingshot

Tags: node.js, file-upload, meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-slingshot

So.. I am new to Meteor and I am trying to upload to a S3 bucket using edgee:slingshot. I have a settings file in the root with the following info.

```
{

  "AWSAccessKeyId": "Key",
  "AWSSecretAccessKey": "Key"

}
```

On the server side I have:

```
Slingshot.createDirective("Test", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: "test",

  acl: "public-read",

  key: function (file) {

    return file.name;
  }
});
```

On the client side I have:

```
 var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");
  var p = doc.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = "This is a new paragraph.";

  try {
    doc.body.appendChild(p);
    console.log(doc);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("Test");

uploader.send(doc, function (error, downloadUrl) {
  if (error) {

    console.error('Error uploading', uploader.xhr.response);
    alert (error);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Worked!");
  }
});
```

I am using Meteor on Windows and the error is:

> S3:AWS key is undefined
>
> Match error: Missing Key 'authorize'.

I am not exactly sure why this error is occurring, so help is much appreciated.

Im running my `settings.json` with `meteor run --settings settings.json` and it works fine.

Comment: you have that keys on `settings.json`? if yes you should run `meteor meteor --settings settings.json`

Comment: Yes! I am running `meteor run --settings settings.json`.

Comment: seems like you are missing the bucket. `bucket String (required) - Name of bucket to use. The default is Meteor.settings.S3Bucket.`

Comment: How would I implement that into my code? Sorry I am a beginner at this..

Comment: i never use slingshot and i can't find an `setting.json` example but try with `"bucket":"S3Bucket"` or `Meteor.settings.S3Bucket`

Comment: I tired that but it still gives me the same error! Thanks Though!

Comment: Which version of slingshot do you use? You can see it from .meteor/versions file. Try to remove package and add with version. `meteor add edgee:slingshot@0.6.1`

Comment: I tried it with that version, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: The error I was getting was because I had Lepozepo/S3 installed. When I removed it, it fixed that problem.

Answer (score 3):

one thing that is missing is the `authorize` function in the directive, which is required (see the [API](https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot)) so add

```
Slingshot.createDirective("Test", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: "test",

  acl: "public-read",

  authorize: function () {
    // do some validation
    // e.g. deny uploads if user is not logged in.
    if (!this.userId) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Login Required");
     }

    return true;
  },

  key: function (file) {

    return file.name;
  }
});
```

Please note that also `maxSize` and `allowedFileTypes` are required, so you should add to client and server side code (e.g. in lib/common.js)

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions("Test", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"],
  maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB (use null for unlimited)
});
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the directive like this on the server side

```
Slingshot.createDirective('Test', Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: 'test',
  maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1,
  acl: 'public-read',
  region: AWS_REGION_OF_UR_BUCKET,
  AWSAccessKeyId: YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  AWSSecretAccessKey: YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  allowedFileTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif'],
  authorize: function() {
   var message;
   if (!this.userId) {
    message = 'Please login before posting files';
    throw new Meteor.Error('Login Required', message);
   }
   return true;
  },
  key: function(file) {
    // admin would be the folder and file would be saved with a timestamp
    return 'admin/' + Date.now() + file.name;
  }
 });
```

Everything else seems to be fine.